# Problem with Array Sorting and Printing it sideways in Fortran 95

Tags: arrays, sorting, arraylist, fortran, fortran95

I am trying to take my array of numbers based on a variable that determines its size and sort it.

The array is created using the random numbers seed on Fortran 95. However when I try to sort it I run into big trouble. It compiles fine, but the array is printed with a lot of asterisks in it.

In addition I wanted to print my array sideways, (for instance something like this: 1 2 3 4 etc.) but I even failed at doing that. I realize that it must be done using the Advance="no" within a DO loop, but apparently that is erroneous as well.

Below is the code that I am using. If anyone is willing to let me know where I may be wrong I would be very grateful. Thanks for your time.

```
    SUBROUTINE Sorter(num, numinteger)

    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT):: num(100)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN):: numinteger

    DO i=1, (numinteger-1)
        min=num(i)
        pos=i
        DO j=i,numinteger
            IF (num(j)<min)THEN
                min=num(j)
                pos=j
            END IF
        END DO
        temp=num(i)
        num(i)=min
        num(pos)=temp
    END DO
    PRINT*, " "
    PRINT*, "Sorted Numbers"
    DO i=1, numinteger
    WRITE(*,23,ADVANCE="NO") num
    23 FORMAT (I2)
    END DO   
    END SUBROUTINE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any spaces between your numbers, but you are also looping over the array, but not incrementing an index... you are asking the computer to print the entire array on each interation.

I think this should be: WRITE(*,23,ADVANCE="NO") num(i)

Comment: I used the 100 in num(100) to simply state the maximum number the array can go to. I don't want my numbers to be greater than 2 digits in fact. So do you think it's because the way I create the random numbers is wrong?

Comment: You might also want to change your FORMAT statement to: FORMAT(I2, 1X)

Comment: Using num(i) instead of simply num made a huge difference and took out a lot of the mess. It works fine now. Thanks so much Jess!!!